# Create a batch file that has options to choose from and loops each time an option is chosen until I end the batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have an application on my Android phone that allows me to create touch replays on my device without actually touching the screen.

This application will create a plain text script that the application then converts to Android debugging code to execute the touches and user input.

The scripting language is very high level for example at the very beginning of any script used by the application the call is simply.

```
// :start
```

It's not a hard task to write a simple script for this application, but I am looking to create a very heavy script that allows me to search a game map that ranges for `X:0,Y:0` to `X:1200,Y:1200` automatically instead of having to literally type that many combinations of coordinates into the game's map search function.

while it is not hard to write this script, it will be very time consuming just as a rough estimate it would require me to write around 2.5 million lines of this simple scripting language to do that, I know I can shave a ton of time if I create a batch file that allows me to simply choose an option to have the batch file create and append the text required in the script to a text file by choosing options instead of having to type each line myself.

Sorry this was so lengthy I wanted to be clear with my question and also provide enough information that my intent for the batch file's operation was also clear.
Basically I need to create an option list of 18 options one being quit from the batch file. The rest I need to cause the choosing of an option to print a specific command for the script into a plain text file.

Comment: If you show us what you've tried in a simplified example and its result? Stackoverflow is not meant to do the work for you.

Comment: I do have a batch file I wrote for this. It doesn't work , i' post it tomorrow when I get home from work.

Comment: Sorry I'll have my batch file that I tried to create loaded tonight. I have done a little more reading since then as well and I believe I understand a few minor mistakes made, but I'll load what I have as soon as I get home tonight.

Comment: while a batch file doesn't seem to be the ideal solution for this problem, neither is providing criticism with no opinion or fact stated as to why, so maybe the next time you think to provide no help, you can also think to provide no comment. It may also serve you well to remember that not everyone asking questions here knows, or is comfortable with another programming language option.

Comment: Well, my comment is that your "question" is pretty confusing: several paragraphs that describe practically nothing and certainly does **NOT** _ask a question!_ The "I wanted to be clear with my question and also provide enough information..." comment combined with the lack of information seems a joke to me with this round off: "I'll post more details soon". You should read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), particularly this part: "Pretend you're seeing the question for the first time: _does it make sense?_".

Comment: I will try to edit this question to make better sense, looking back I can see how it turned out to be like a mathematical word problem where literally none of the dialogue pertained to the actual question and was mainly relational information that could distract someone.  But the question is as simple and complete as the post title "create a batch file that has options to choose from and loops each time an option is chosen until I end the batch file"  should have been "how do I create a menu of options in a batch file, and return to the menu until I choose to end the batch"

Comment: But there again, the entire question is covered in the post title with no additional information needed to answer the question. Which would leave the subject line blank.

Comment: @Aacini  I guess sometimes you don't know how to ask a question where it can be understood, until the question is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer i finally worked out after much futher research trial and error is this.

// you will want to ECHO these options after setting your :MENU anchor like this.

```
:MENU
ECHO.
```

// the ECHO's below hold no special value, it is simply how i chose to create a minorly graphical explanation of what the user should do, and what options they have to choose from to build a script. However they are still significant because without them, the user would not know their options

```
ECHO ###################################################
ECHO #   Select start to begin building your script    #
ECHO ###################################################
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - 1
ECHO 2 - 2
ECHO 3 - 3
ECHO 4 - 4
ECHO 5 - 5
ECHO 6 - 6
ECHO 7 - 7
ECHO 8 - 8
ECHO 9 - 9
ECHO 10 - 0
ECHO 11 - CHECKBOX
ECHO 12 - GO
ECHO 13 - X_COORDINATES
ECHO 14 - Y_COORDINATES
ECHO 15 - SEARCH
ECHO 16 - START
ECHO 17 - QUIT
ECHO.
```

// this is one way to implement a menu for a user to choose from, 
the `IF%M%==1` asigns a variable for the batchfile, while the `GOTO 1` Assigns what should happen whe the variable `1` is called by the user input.

```
SET /P M=TYPE 1-16 THEN PRESS ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO 1
IF %M%==2 GOTO 2
IF %M%==3 GOTO 3
IF %M%==4 GOTO 4
IF %M%==5 GOTO 5
IF %M%==6 GOTO 6
IF %M%==7 GOTO 7
IF %M%==8 GOTO 8
IF %M%==9 GOTO 9
IF %M%==10 GOTO 0
IF %M%==11 GOTO CHECKBOX
IF %M%==12 GOTO GO
IF %M%==13 GOTO X_COORDINATES
IF %M%==14 GOTO Y_COORDINATES
IF %M%==15 GOTO SEARCH
IF %M%==16 GOTO START
IF %M%==17 QUIT
```

// the `:START` anchor is the part of the script that will execute if a user were to input 16 as their choice. See the variable above `IF%M%==16 GOTO START` `GOTO` calls `START` in the file and placing the colon in front of start tells the batch file this is where to begin executing commands if your looking to execute the commands associated with the start option.

```
:START
```

// normally you do not have to cd all the way through the tree, i have to because i have an environment variable that has been changed, and depending on what your using the menu for if you are not printing output to a text file then the following commands may be different for your purpose.

```
cd..
cd..
cd C:\Documents and Settings\
cd C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\
cd C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\
cd C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\
```

// now that i have changed my directory with the above `cd` commands, the next line prints `:start` to the speedSearch.txt file in the directory (this `:start` is not to be confused with the `:START` anchor, it just so happens that the scripting language i am writing the output in requires `:start` as its first line).

```
@ECHO :start>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
```

// `@ECHO` tells the command at the time of execution on this line output the following information. the `>` portion of this line redirects the `:start` that follows the `@ECHO` to print into the text file speedSearch.txt

```
@ECHO :start>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
```

// The above line does the same thing but prints the output to sSlog.txt

```
GOTO :MENU
```

// the `GOTO :MENU` at the end of the block tells the batch file, that command execution stops on this line and returns to the menu.
// Here again we have an anchor for the search function( this does not search the batch file, this is the search function my script will invoke in a game i am playing when i run the script.)

```
:SEARCH
@ECHO touchPress 0 493 2148>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
```

// Once again the `@ECHO` will execute  the command that follows it on this  line, this time you see two `>` redirection charachters, this is becuase a single `>` will write or overwrite whats in the file as well as create the file if it is not found in most newer versions of windows from (win2000 on i believe), while `>>` appends the information to the file on the next line.
this time i am redirecting the `touchPress 0 493 2148` to the text file.

```
@ECHO SEARCH>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
```

//While you can see here that i am redirecting the word `SEARCH` to a different file, i did this because trying to find your place in your progress with the lines in the scripting language looking like this.

```
touchPress 0 493 2148
sleep
touchPress 0 529 1212
sleep
etc...
etc...
```

// is pretty hard to do, it means i would need memorize what each `touchPress` coordinate command means. With simple things like `SEARCH` and `1` printing to a separate file i can look at the sSlog.txt file if i get lost in the process of choosing options from the batch script, or need to step away from my desk for a minute i can easily understand which step i stopped on when i was interupted or side tracked.

```
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
```

// here you can see that i am sending the scripting languages `sleep` call and its interval `590` to the speedSearch.txt file this is because the scripting language on my phone requires a sleep between each line of the scripting language, so instead of writing an option for `sleep` i have chosen to include it in each block after its original command redirection. However i did not redirect it to the sSlog.txt file because i don't need the extra clutter, i know its going to redirect it to the actual script so i dont need it in my sSlog.txt file.

```
GOTO :MENU
:X_COORDINATES
@ECHO touchPress 0 529 1221>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO X_COORDINATES_highlight>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:Y_COORDINATES
@ECHO touchPress 0 1131 1208>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO Y_COORDINATES_highlight>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@echo sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:1
@ECHO touchPress 0 220 1800>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number1>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:2
@ECHO touchPress 0 582 1800>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number2>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:3
@ECHO touchPress 0 956 1800>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number3>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:4
@ECHO touchPress 0 220 2040>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number4>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:5
@ECHO touchPress 0 582 2040>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number5>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:6
@ECHO touchPress 0 956 2040>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number6>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:7
@ECHO touchPress 0 220 2212>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number7>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:8
@ECHO touchPress 0 582 2212>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number8>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:9
@ECHO touchPress 0 956 2212>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number9>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:0
@ECHO touchPress 0 582 2462>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number0>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:CHECKBOX
@ECHO touchPress 0 1315 2451>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO CHECKBOX>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:GO
@ECHO touchPress 0 825 1495>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO go>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
GOTO :MENU
```

// Last but not least the last option is to quit the batch file.

```
:QUIT
@ECHO :end>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
```

// what i have done here is once again instead of making an option specifically to redirect the `:end` command to the speedSearch.txt file, i chose to redirect it with the quit option, by calling its `ECHO` and redirection before i called the actual `exit` command.

```
@ECHO :end>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO exit
```

this batch file does exactly what i was looking to do, however because of my environment variable issue if i were to try and deploy it, it would not work on any other machine because of the file path calls to `"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"` would cause an error on other machines lacking that file path, which is going to be all of them unless you purposely created a file tree in that exact structure just to get it to work.

The whole script together lookslike this and you can copy paste it if you would like to play with it to see how it works and tailor it for your own use.

```
@ECHO OFF
COLOR 40
TITLE=Search Alogorithym Creator
ECHO.
ECHO              #############################################
ECHO              # Created by King Ironwraith of kingdom #72 #
ECHO              #############################################
ECHO              #              Copyright 2015               #
ECHO              #############################################
ECHO WScript.Sleep^(WScript.Arguments^(0^)^) >"%temp%\sleep.vbs" && cscript "%temp%\sleep.vbs" 5000 >nul
CLS
@ECHO OFF
COLOR 04
TITLE=PERMISSIONS
ECHO you may use this batch file to create you own custom auto-search script
ECHO for use with the HIRO-MACRO android application. I am not the author 
ECHO of HIRO-MACRO and make no claim to the suitability of the application's use
ECHO  you can find the application in the Google Playstore.
ECHO WScript.Sleep^(WScript.Arguments^(0^)^) >"%temp%\sleep.vbs" && cscript "%temp%\sleep.vbs" 5000 >nul
CLS
@ECHO OFF
COLOR 40
TITLE=WARNING
ECHO.
ECHO !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ECHO !! WARNING !!! WARNING !!! WARNING !!! WARNING !!! WARNING !!! WARNING !!! WARNING !!
ECHO !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ECHO !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ECHO !! you must have a rooted android Device to use the HIRO-MACRO application, if you !!
ECHO !! do not know what "ROOTED" means, you can find more information on what root is, !!
ECHO !! and how to safely root your device at http://forum.xda-developers.com/          !!
ECHO !! there are some risks when rooting a device, you assume liability of all risks,  !!
ECHO !! should you decide to attempt to root your device to use this batch file and the !!
ECHO !! resulting script in conjunction with the HIRO-MACRO application.                !!
ECHO !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ECHO !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ECHO !! WARNING !!! WARNING !!! WARNING !!! WARNING !!! WARNING !!! WARNING !!! WARNING !!
ECHO !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ECHO. 
ECHO WScript.Sleep^(WScript.Arguments^(0^)^) >"%temp%\sleep.vbs" && cscript "%temp%\sleep.vbs" 12000 >nul
CLS
TITLE=Search Algorithym Creator
:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO ###################################################
ECHO # Select an Option to begin building your script  #
ECHO ###################################################
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - 1
ECHO 2 - 2
ECHO 3 - 3
ECHO 4 - 4
ECHO 5 - 5
ECHO 6 - 6
ECHO 7 - 7
ECHO 8 - 8
ECHO 9 - 9
ECHO 10 - 0
ECHO 11 - CHECKBOX
ECHO 12 - GO
ECHO 13 - X_COORDINATES
ECHO 14 - Y_COORDINATES
ECHO 15 - SEARCH
ECHO 16 - START
ECHO 17 - QUIT
ECHO.
SET /P M=TYPE 1-16 THEN PRESS ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO 1
IF %M%==2 GOTO 2
IF %M%==3 GOTO 3
IF %M%==4 GOTO 4
IF %M%==5 GOTO 5
IF %M%==6 GOTO 6
IF %M%==7 GOTO 7
IF %M%==8 GOTO 8
IF %M%==9 GOTO 9
IF %M%==10 GOTO 0
IF %M%==11 GOTO CHECKBOX
IF %M%==12 GOTO GO
IF %M%==13 GOTO X_COORDINATES
IF %M%==14 GOTO Y_COORDINATES
IF %M%==15 GOTO SEARCH
IF %M%==16 GOTO START
IF %M%==17 QUIT

:START
cd..
cd..
cd C:\Documents and Settings\
cd C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\
cd C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\
cd C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\
@ECHO :start>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO :start>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
GOTO :MENU
:SEARCH
@ECHO touchPress 0 493 2148>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO SEARCH>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:X_COORDINATES
@ECHO touchPress 0 529 1221>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO X_COORDINATES_highlight>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:Y_COORDINATES
@ECHO touchPress 0 1131 1208>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO Y_COORDINATES_highlight>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@echo sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:1
@ECHO touchPress 0 220 1800>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number1>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:2
@ECHO touchPress 0 582 1800>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number2>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:3
@ECHO touchPress 0 956 1800>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number3>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:4
@ECHO touchPress 0 220 2040>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number4>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:5
@ECHO touchPress 0 582 2040>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number5>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:6
@ECHO touchPress 0 956 2040>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number6>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:7
@ECHO touchPress 0 220 2212>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number7>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:8
@ECHO touchPress 0 582 2212>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number8>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:9
@ECHO touchPress 0 956 2212>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number9>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:0
@ECHO touchPress 0 582 2462>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO number0>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:CHECKBOX
@ECHO touchPress 0 1315 2451>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO CHECKBOX>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO sleep 590>>speedSearch.txt
GOTO :MENU
:GO
@ECHO touchPress 0 825 1495>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO go>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
GOTO :MENU
:QUIT
@ECHO :end>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\sSlog.txt"
@ECHO :end>>"C:\Documents and Settings\Master Terminal\Desktop\speedSearchFiles\speedSearch.txt"
@ECHO exit
```

//finally you can see in the whole project there are some lines that i did not explain.

```
 WScript.Sleep^(WScript.Arguments^(0^)^) >"%temp%\sleep.vbs" && cscript "%temp%\sleep.vbs" 5000 >nul
```

// This line of code actually compiles a small .vbs script on the fly to cause the window to wait, it will work on most windows machines from Win2000 and up. the `5000 >nul` part of this code instructs the window to wait for five seconds before continuing execution.

//the `COLOR 40` is setting the command window background and foreground colors, you can find a list of the color codes on google if you want to implement them in your own scripts.

// the `TITLE=Search Alogorithym Creator` line changes the WINDOW title to Search Algorithym Creator

// the `CLS` clears whats already been printed on the screen.

Comment: I was amazed at first that someone can posted this large and complete answer based on the null information given in the question, until I realized that the answerer and the OP _is the same person!_ There are a couple points you must care of when you answer your own question, in first place that it be a _real question_ that can be understood and answered by other people; otherwise the whole topic is not suitable for SO site. IMHO this "question/answer" pair is not useful for the users of this forum, and perhaps nor even for yourself...

Comment: The question is the post title, and the content in the subject box was to clarify what I was trying to do, I will edit the subject matter to make this question valid according to everyone else. As to your question of this being a valid working answer that would serve someone else or myself, while I could only speculate if it would help others, I can tell you as a fact, this answer fully serves the purpose I intended, and is working perfectly for my implementation of the code.